# How to save an inventory using binary c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to save my inventory. My inventory script works just fine but when I want to save it to a binary file it doesn't save. I have no idea why this code is not working. Can you help me?

Here is my inventory code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

namespace SimpleInventory
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Header("InventoryUI")]
        [SerializeField] private UI.InventoryUI inventoryUI = null;

        private Dictionary<Item, int> inventory = new Dictionary<Item, int>();

        public Dictionary<Item, int> GetInventory => inventory;
        public int NumUniqueItems => inventory.Count;
        public delegate void OnInventoryChange();
        public OnInventoryChange onInventoryChange;

        public delegate void OnAddNewItem(Item item, int count);
        public OnAddNewItem onAddNewItem;

        public Text additemtext;

        private void Start()
        {
            if (inventoryUI)
                inventoryUI.InitializeUI(this);

            additemtext.enabled = false;
        }

        public void AddToInventory(Item item, int count = 1)
        {
            if (!inventory.ContainsKey(item))
                inventory.Add(item, count);
            else
                inventory[item] += count;

            Debug.Log($"Added { count} of { item.name} to the inventory");
            StartCoroutine(itemTextnum());
            additemtext.text = "+ " + count + " "+ item.name + " collected";

            onInventoryChange?.Invoke();
        }

        public void RemoveFromInventory(Item item, int count) // item satma,
        {
            if (!inventory.ContainsKey(item))
                throw new System.Exception("the dictionary does not contain that item");

            if (inventory[item] >= count)
            {
                inventory[item] -= 1;
                Debug.Log("count" + count);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("count to zero");
                inventory[item] = 0;
            }
            onInventoryChange?.Invoke();
        }
        
        IEnumerator itemTextnum()
        {
            additemtext.enabled = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            additemtext.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is binary:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace SimpleInventory
{
    public class SaveManager
    {
        private Inventory inv;    // the Dictionary used to save and load data to/from disk
        protected string savePath;
        public SaveManager()
        {
            this.savePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/inventory.inv";
            this.inv = new Inventory();
            this.loadDataFromDisk();
        }

        /**
         * Saves the save data to the disk
         */
        public void saveDataToDisk()
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Create(savePath);
            bf.Serialize(file, inv);
            file.Close();
        }

        /**
         * Loads the save data from the disk
         */
        public void loadDataFromDisk()
        {
            if (File.Exists(savePath))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                FileStream file = File.Open(savePath, FileMode.Open);
                this.inv = (Inventory)bf.Deserialize(file);
                file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My inventory script works just fine but when I want to save it to a binary file it doesn't save. I have no idea why this code is not working. Can you help me?

I add my inventoryUI code which i think the script i should try to save:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


namespace SimpleInventory
{
    

    public class InventoryUI : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Inventory inventory = null;

        [SerializeField] int numSlotstoCreate = 15;


        [SerializeField] ItemSlotUI[] itemSlots = null;
        [SerializeField]  GameObject slotUIPrefab = null;

        [SerializeField]  private Transform contentParent = null;

        public GameObject inventoryAcma;

        public GameObject envanterarka;


        public string savePath = "/Inventory.save";

        public void Start()
        {
            inventoryAcma.SetActive(false);
            envanterarka.SetActive(false);

           

           
        }


        public void Update()
        {
            
        }
        /*
        public void Save()
        {
            string saveData = JsonUtility.ToJson(this, true);
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Create(string.Concat(Application.persistentDataPath, savePath));
            bf.Serialize(file, saveData);
            file.Close();
            
        }

        public void Load()
        {
            if (File.Exists(string.Concat(Application.persistentDataPath, savePath)))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                FileStream file = File.Open(string.Concat(Application.persistentDataPath, savePath), FileMode.Open);
                JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(bf.Deserialize(file).ToString(), this);
                file.Close();
            }
        }
        */
        public void InitializeUI(Inventory inventory)

        {
            this.inventory = inventory;

            CreateItemSlots();
            UpdateItemSlots();
            
            inventory.onInventoryChange += UpdateItemSlots;
        }


        public void CreateItemSlots()
        {
            itemSlots = new ItemSlotUI[numSlotstoCreate];
           
        
            
           
            for (int i = 0; i < numSlotstoCreate; i++)
            {
               
               
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(slotUIPrefab);
                obj.transform.SetParent(contentParent.transform,false);

                itemSlots[i] = obj.GetComponent<ItemSlotUI>();
                
            }
           
        }

        

        private void UpdateItemSlots()
        {
            int i = 0;
            
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Item, int> kvp in inventory.GetInventory)
            {

                if (kvp.Value == 0)

                    itemSlots[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);

                else
                {
                    itemSlots[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    itemSlots[i].UpdateSlotUI(this, kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

                    
                   
                }

                i++;
            }
         
            for (int j = i; j < itemSlots.Length; j++)
            {
                
                itemSlots[j].gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }

            
        }


        

       

        
       
         
         

        public void itemClicked(Item item)
        {
            inventory.RemoveFromInventory(item, 1);
        }

        public void InventoryAcmaButton()
        {
            inventoryAcma.SetActive(true);
            envanterarka.SetActive(true);
        }
        public void InventoryKapamaButton()
        {
            inventoryAcma.SetActive(false);
            envanterarka.SetActive(false);
        }





       

       
    }


}
```

Comment: When you debug this, is your save method called? Does that inventory contain items?

Comment: I think my save method is not working. I dont now how to call save method since the script is not monobehaviour. Inventory does contain items.

Comment: In your posted code, the SaveManager has a private field "inv" that gets saved and loaded by the methods there, but nothing else accesses it. Are you really saving inventory items to *that* field or to a totally unrelated instance of Inventory?

Comment: Hello. I've added my inventoryUI which i think is the to deal for saving. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "using statement".
You can read about "using statement" from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

```
static void BinarySerialize(dynamic database)
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var fs = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        bf.Serialize(fs, database);
    }
}

static void BinaryDeserialize(out dynamic database)
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var fs = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        database = bf.Deserialize(fs) as Inventory[];
    }
}
```

Comment: It is an excellent idea to use a "using" here, but I don't think it will solve the posted issue